# In Visual Foxpro, how do I change date format {^yyyy-mm-dd} to {dd/mm/yyyy} when building an EXE?

Tags: date, format, visual-foxpro

In Visual Foxpro, how do I change date format {^yyyy-mm-dd}  to {dd/mm/yyyy} when building an EXE file?

Comment: I have "do setups" in Dataenvironment BeforeOpenTables. In that setups.prg you can include "SET DATE DMY"

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of Global Settings in Vfp, and `Set Date` is one of them. Which like many other settings is "Scoped to the Current DataSession".
So that when you start the Vfp IDE, or a custom myProject.EXE outside the IDE,
you would get all default settings, which is `American`.

When your Exe starts it runs the code from the Project's "main" member which can be a PRG code file.
So that you can put a few lines there like

```
Set Date YMD && yymmdd date, or:
Set Date DMY && ddmmyy
Set Century On && four digit year YYYY
Set Mark To "/" && DD/MM/YYYY
```

There are several further Settings like `Set Hours` and related and also `Set SysFormats On` which is an "all-in-one" and means taking over the current Windows O/S locale settings more or less.
`SET SYSFORMATS` is scoped to the current data session, just like `SET DATE` so that you would need to run that code again as soon as you create a new `Data Session`, like for example when you run a `Form` that has a property `DataSession`=2, or when you create a `Session` object.

**NB:**
You can lookup all these Settings and object properties in the local Vfp Help file via `F1` key.
See also https://www.vfphelp.com/help/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

To add to Stefan's response (which is perfect), I would advise creating an "Environment" object where you can define all the `SET` options you need as parameters and set them all with a function in all your forms/reports as well as your application entry point.

We do something like this in our application (1000+ forms/reports):

```
THISFORM.AddObject("oCusEnv", "CustomEnv")
THISFORM.oCusEnv.SetEnv()
```

Using `THISFORM.AddObject()` ensures the `CustomEnv` object inherits the forms datasession so the changes to the environment in `SetEnv()` will apply to the forms private datasession.

**Note**: We don't make use of `DataEnvironment` objects, if you are using them, I believe this would be the best place to issue any `SET` statements as the form inherits the `DataEnvironment`'s datasession.